# catch-and-replace Rx Observable stream/sequence

Tags: error-handling, rxjs

Say I have an observable compromised of two remote AJAX calls that are already exposed as Observable's. These streams are flatMaps of the sponse to a sequence of values.

```
var remoteData = Rx.Observable.merge(
  data1,
  data2);
```

For sake of argument imagine the following definitions:

```
var data1 = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]);     // Multiple items!
var data2 = Rx.Observable.throw("Whoops!");
```

I would like to then either *get all data1 and all data2*, as fetched or if there is *any error* use the cached data.

However if I were to write `var dataOrCache = remoteData.catch(cachedData)` it would *append* to the output stream only adding the cached data *after* the error. This is because [`catch`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md) merely continues the sequence from a different observable:

> *Continues* an observable sequence that is terminated by an exception with the next observable sequence.

This is problematic because the error might result from data2 (or even later in the data1 steam); yet the cacheData should *superseded* any and *all* results from an err'ing source.

For example, if `cacheData = Rx.Observable.from(["cached"])` the final sequence would be `[1,2,3,"cached"]` when it the desired goal is `["cached"]`.

I've looked at [Getting Started: Errors](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/errors.md), but am unable how to handle this situation as it is not one of the listed scenarios. The 'caching' situation shown assumes a fail-fast observables that error before returning *any* results.

I am looking for a way to handle this via a different stream composition or one of the built-in operator methods and I do not want to unwrap this to an explicit  observable source.

Comment: Can you give some precisions about your questions? There are four possibilities : No error, both ajax call are erroneous, data1 is erroneous and data2 no, and the other way around. If there is no error, I understand there is nothing to do, if both ajax are erroneous, then the only source is the cached data. Do you want to wait for the status of both ajax call before deciding on a course of action? Or do you want to use the cache as soon as one of the two ajax call returns with error?

Comment: @user3743222 The 'crux' of the problem is that either data1 or data2 sequences may err *at any time* (either the connection failed, or say parsing the data failed). I've since moved to a fail-fast `concat(response1, response2).catch(..).flatMap(expandResults)` but that is avoiding the problem posed here. The cached data should be used when `merge(..)` errs and should replace *all* (now questionable) data generated up until then; that is, the source sequences should be used only when they complete successfully.

Comment: @user3743222 I've added some example observable creators to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood everything but :

- if you want to get values from cache when the ajax call fails, you can do something like this:

`var remoteData = Rx.Observable.zip( 
                           data1.catch(getFromCache('data1')), 
                           data2.catch(getFromCache('data2'))
                     )`

This uses the instance version of the `catch` operator, and the signature `Rx.Observable.prototype.catch(handler)`: cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md

Your `getFromCache` function must return a promise or an observable.
`remoteData` will emit a value when both data1 and data2 are fetched, whether from cache or from ajax call.

- If you want to take values from cache as soon as one of the ajax call fails:

`var remoteData = Rx.Observable.zip(data1, data2).catch(getDataFromCache('data1','data2'))`

I haven't tested but let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: This poses the same problem but moves it a level: catch appends-to/continues a sequence so an err that comes after the first item will still have resulted in at least one item on the stream. (In the particular case of AJAX I could make the entire promise / handler callback fail - and return a single-valued stream on success - but this just avoids the initial question.)

Comment: The second options seems to be working fine. I tested with your examples for data1 and data2, and the following `var remoteData = Rx.Observable.zip(data1, data2).catch(Rx.Observable.just(42))`, the helper function `function cs(data) {console.log("data: ", data)}` and the subscription `remoteData.subscribe(cs, console.log, cs)`. The output is `42` as expected.

Comment: By the way, the `zip` operator is waiting for all its sources to produce one value (here `data1` and `data2`) before zipping, so there is nothing emitted in the stream unless both sources have completed the ajax call successfully. If one of the source has an error, the zipped observable call its error handler (which is caught by the handler you gave the `catch` operator). If one of the source completes, the `zip` operator also completes. This is a crucial difference with `merge` where the first source to emit leads to the merged source emitting too.

Comment: did that solve your problem? don't forget to accept the answer if that's the case

Comment: what about [`materialize`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/materialize.md) AJAX stream and getting value from cache on error?

Comment: @eryk : interesting. Is there a way to 'dematerialize' the materialized values you get, so that you can get back the actual result of the ajax call? This does not say: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/materialize.md

Comment: Sure, there is [`dematerialize` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/dematerialize.md) as well.

Comment: Yes, but `dematerialize`is the inverse function. I was thinking about a way to unwrap the materialized value. So, after some search, it seems like a materialized value is an instance of `Rx.Notification` which has the method `kind` which allows to know whether the notification is a standard value, a `completed`, or `error` value. Cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/notification.md#hasvalue